# How can I calculate the amount of heat my copper water trap can shed?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

My small (1.5hp) air compressor is connected to a water trap made of 8mm copper of about 4 metres length. The idea is that you push the compressed air through the piping which cools it, condensing the water out (which you drain away) and thus sending dry air to your air tools.

I know the system works, but i would like to understand the maths behind it. I started trying to work it out with help of the below graph from engineeringtoolbox.com but didn't know where to go next.

[image: heat dissipation of uninsulated copper tube - lines represent temperature difference.]

How can I mathematically determine the temperature drop of the air in the piping? We can assume an average ambient temperature of 25 degrees Celcius with air coming out of the compressor at 100 degrees Celcius.

Comment: you might try putting this on the engineering stack exchange, there are lots of guys over there who know how to routinely do this sort of analysis.